# Jenkins GitHub plugin can't choose my credentials

Tags: git, github, jenkins, docker

I got very strange behavior that has never happened before, when I try to configure the GitHub server in Jenkins general configuration to set up webhooks auto.

The drop down menu doesn't display my registered credentials. I was always be able to do that, but suddenly I don't know what's happening. I tried to uninstall the plugin, restarting Jenkins, kill the Jenkins Docker container and configure all the stuff again ... still I got the same issue.

[image]

There is no other option other than none, and when I add new credentials I still get *None* as the only option...

Comment: What happens when you click on the "Add" button? Have you tried adding other credentials?

Comment: yes this is what I can't understand when I add new ones I still get none as the only option

Comment: Github plugin only accepts plain text credentials (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plain+Credentials+Plugin). Have you created one manually or via the Advanced... options?

Comment: I created them with the add

Comment: You need a personal access token from Github, you can create one with these instructions: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-AutomaticMode%28Jenkinsmanageshooksforjobsbyitself%29

Comment: I did i get this over and over again Can't create GH token - {"message":"Validation Failed","errors":[{"resource":"OauthAccess","code":"already_exists","field":"description"}],"documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization"}

Comment: already exist and in the drope down menu I have NONE !!

Comment: You can remove your token from https://github.com/settings/tokens and let the plugin generate a new one

Comment: I'm glad this solved your issue :) Haha I actually had this exact same problem yesterday when setting up the Github plugin in my Jenkins service

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is that the GitHub plugin [only accepts plain text credentials](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plain+Credentials+Plugin).

The GitHub access token can be created manually, or automatically via the Advanced... options as described [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-AutomaticMode%28Jenkinsmanageshooksforjobsbyitself%29).

In case you already have an access token in GitHub (you'll get an error in Jenkins), you can [remove it in Github](https://github.com/settings/tokens). Then you can let Jenkins generate the token and select it in the Credentials menu.

Comment: If you have to add the plain text credentials by hand, what do you put in the "secret" line. Does it have the userid and token in there?

Comment: I was NOT able to see my credentials with a manually create a token. I only saw them when I created them automatically using the method described in the link shared by @Hilborn

Comment: this doens't seem to be a thing anymore