# How to add credential when configuring github server on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am setting up Jenkins webhook. When a change pushed to github server, the job on Jenkins should be triggered. Below is what I did but failed to add credential.

In `Manage Jenkins` -> `Configure system` -> `GitHub Servers` section, I added the link 'https://api.github.com' as Github Server API URL. Then I added a credential by clicking the `Add` button. But after adding the credential, it is not shown on the `credential` dropdown. I have installed Credential Plugin on my jenkins but still it is not showing.  See below picture.

How can I let add credential on this field?

[image]

> EDIT1

The credential I added is shown as below. None of them is shown on the dropdown menu in the above picture.

[image]

Comment: What kind of credential did you add? As @CossetteN said, you may have not added one supported by the plugin. This is admittedly confusing...

Comment: I have added the credential screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Can you include a picture of the credentials screen filled out?  That way we can try to determine if there is a problem with the set up.

Comment: I'm using the same plugin and I'm experiencing the same thing.  I did some more searching and found another question that seems to be addressing the same issue.  Have you tried using the Plain Credentials Plugin?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500729/jenkins-github-plugin-cant-choose-my-credentials