# Credentials added in jenkins are not displayed for HipChat plugin

Tags: jenkins, hipchat

I have build jobs created in Jenkins and I want to publish the Job results to a HipChat room. I'm using [HipChat plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HipChat+Plugin). The issue here is that I am able to save my credentials in Jenkins Global credentials but I don't see any credentials listed for HipChat notification. I get to see the same credentials for SCM Checkout but not in HipChat notifier.

FYI, I went through the stack overflow link: [GITHub plugin Jenkins credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36500729/jenkins-github-plugin-cant-choose-my-credentials) but it was not that much useful for me.

Please, if someone has a workaround or if you can see if I'm doing something wrong, let me know.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to use credentials of "secret text" kind and use an OAuth Token V2 by doing the following:

1. Go to https://YourHipChat.hipchat.com/account/api and login (Replace "YourHipChat" in the url, with your company or whatever)
2. Click on Rooms-->YourChatRoom-->Integrations
3. Find Jenkins and add it.
4. Grab the token in the configure tab.
5. Paste the token into the "secret" field in your Jenkins credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find solution to the credential issue I faced but found another way for what I need. Instead of the HipChat plugin, I used HipChat notifier plugin from [Github link](https://github.com/yagince/hipchat-notifier-plugin), created a access token for chatroom and used the access token in HipChat notifier. It did exactly what I need.